# Flutter Stepper overflow

Tags: flutter

Hi I am creating a horizontal stepper but it's getting overflow to the right any fixes ?

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Stepper(
    type: StepperType.horizontal,
    physics:
        const ScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
    currentStep: _currentStep,
    onStepTapped: (step) => tapped(step),
    onStepContinue: continued,
    onStepCancel: cancel,
    steps: <Step>[
      Step(
        title: const Text('Personal Info'),
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Address'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
        state: _currentStep >= 0
            ? StepState.complete
            : StepState.disabled,
      ),
      Step(
        title: const Text('Company Info'),
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Home Address'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postcode'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
        state: _currentStep >= 1
            ? StepState.complete
            : StepState.disabled,
      ),
      Step(
        title: const Text('Request Detail'),
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Mobile Number'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
        state: _currentStep >= 2
            ? StepState.complete
            : StepState.disabled,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

have tried with listview and giving it horizontal axis but doesn't work any fixes in the code will be great thanks in advance and what can be the best way to manage stepper

also tried
physics:
const ScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()), don't know this can help

Comment: Have you  tried wrapping the stepper with SingleChildScrollView then as for scrollDirection from SingleChildScrollView is Axis.horizontal

Comment: tried after you suggest doesn't work that way